# Mysql - group by always displays a column of the first row?

Tags: mysql, group-by

For example i have a table `test`:

```
number   | text | date1      | date2
1        | a    | 2015-02-21 | 2015-02-23
1        | b    | 2015-02-22 | 2015-02-23
1        | c    | 2015-02-22 | 2015-02-24
1        | d    | 2015-02-21 | 2015-02-24
2        | a    | 2015-02-21 | 2015-02-21
2        | b    | 2015-02-22 | 2015-02-23
```

I need to display text for each number date1 and date2 last.
Desired result set:

```
number   | text | date1      | date2
1        | c    | 2015-02-22 | 2015-02-24
2        | b    | 2015-02-22 | 2015-02-23
```

Correctly working SELECT:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (SELECT
    *
  FROM
    test
  ORDER BY
    date1 DESC, date2 DESC
  ) as tab
GROUP BY
  number
```

Is it always this will work correctly?

Is it always displays the data from the first row grouping item?

Comment: What is the purpose of your sub-query? What are you trying to achieve with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: could explain more detailed your requirements: `text for each number date1 and date2 last` so why it returns 2 rows but not 6?

Comment: I want to display only one value for each number from the last date. sub-query is used to sort the data. Without sub-query: 
`SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY number` in result i get:
number   | text | date1      | date2
1        | a    | 2015-02-21 | 2015-02-23
2        | a    | 2015-02-21 | 2015-02-21

Comment: the question is if there is row `(1,b,2015-02-20,2015-02-28)` and `(1,c,2015-02-22,2015-02-25)` what must result looks like?

Comment: If there is row (1,b,2015-02-20,2015-02-28) and (1,c,2015-02-22,2015-02-25)
result must look (1,c,2015-02-22,2015-02-25).
First i need check date1, if max date1 is more than 1 then i check date2

Comment: why `c` and not `b` what is criteria?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I get your goal, but try this query:

```
SELECT
  test.number,
  test.text,
  t1.date1,
  t1.date2,
FROM test
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT
    number, 
    MAX(date1) as date1,
    MAX(date2) as date2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN date2>=date1 THEN date2 ELSE date1 END) as dateMax
  FROM
    test
  GROUP BY number
  ) as t1
ON t1.number=test.number 
   AND (t1.dateMax = test.date1
   OR t1.dateMax = test.date2)
```

Comment: First i need check date1, if max date1 is more than 1 then i check date2.
This query not working when i have for example: (1,b,2015-02-20,2015-02-28) and (1,c,2015-02-22,2015-02-25). If in one row i have biggest date1 and in other i have biggest  date2

Comment: I already asked you - so what is your criteria to choose text? you need just the biggest one among date1 and date2 ??

Comment: The biggest date1, if is more than one the biggest date1, then check date2. I need first element from sort order by date1 DESC, date2 DESC

Comment: WHAT!?  check updated query, if it doesn't match to your goal - I am done here anyway

Comment: For data (1,b,2015-02-20,2015-02-28) and (1,c,2015-02-22,2015-02-25) result must look (1,c,2015-02-22,2015-02-25). In this query i get (1,b,2015-02-22,2015-02-28)

Comment: yes, because date2 bigger than date1 and you was asked for the latest date. anyway. you have my query, and you have your head and brain. if you need - you can finish that. if you can't - try to ask other people. I am done!